# Popping Messages from MIDI Tracks

Tags: midi, mido

I have type 0 MIDI file, containing the track with only 269 meta-messages that I'd like to keep the header chunk and the last one for the end of the file.

```
for i, msg in enumerate(mid.tracks[0]):
    if i > 10 or i < len(mid.tracks[0])-1:
        if msg.is_meta:
            mid.tracks[0].pop(i)
```

The above code, does not do this. In fact, it removes exactly half of the messages (135 of them), it also removes the beginning and the end and I have to runs it a few times to get it to close to 10 meta messages!

The [library](https://mido.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lib.html) says:

> pop([index]) → item -- remove and return item at index (default last).
>   Raises IndexError if list is empty or index is out of range.

I also tried another way, but again, each time only removes half of that. So I need to runs the loop few times to get it close to size I want:

```
while len(mid.tracks[0])>16:
    for i, msg in enumerate(mid.tracks[0]):
        if msg.is_meta and hasattr(msg, 'data'): 
            if len(msg.data) == 7:
                mid.tracks[0].remove(msg)

for i, msg in enumerate(mid.tracks[0]):
    if msg.is_meta:
        print(i, msg)
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: You really should not modify an object inside a loop over the object. When you call `pop(i)` you setting yourself up for trouble. Perhaps create a "remove" list and remove them seperately.

Comment: It seems it pops randomly! I just did that. and edited the OP. Thank you the answer.

Comment: could you please comment on this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61305523/adding-midi-chords-at-specific-metamessage-time . I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be faster. Note, the code may not match your data exactly. If you post your value of mid.tracks[0], I can give you a better result.

```
t = mid.tracks[0] # shorthand to simplify code
keep = t[:10] + t[-1:] # get first ten and last one
# keep only the non-meta ones
result = [msg for msg in keep if not msg.is_meta]
```

Note: revised according to comment.

Comment: your second line: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "MetaMessage") to list!

Comment: Try `t[-1:]` instead of `t[-1]`. If not, then try `[t[-1]]`. It all depends on what exactly is in you `mid.tracks[0]` object. Perhaps you can post a dump of the object?